Sending follow up email after immediate open in Journey Builder
I need to know how to wait until 15 days after sending an email in Journey Builder and whoever opens the email during that time can move on to the next activity immediately, without having to wait for the 15-day waiting time to end. . Sorry for my English. Thank you

You cannot do this with Journey Builder alone, you'd need to monitor the opens with another scheduled process that ingest people into the follow up Journey. Let me try to explain the structure:

You have your current journey, only with the first email send.
Build a SQL Query that checks for opens in this journey, and adds people to a Data Extension as soon as they open
Build a Journey with the send you want to send as soon as they open, and use the Data Extension from step 2 as the Entry Source.

To read more about how to work with Data Views, in DESelect we've written this  article.
Hope this makes sense!

Your question inspired my thought process, which resulted in this article. It explains how you are able to track opens, and trigger "something" in real time, using Ampscript.
This something can be a call to an Wait By Activity, which awaits an API request to release the contact and allow it to progress through the journey. It can be a transactional email, or a brand new journey altogether. Only your imagination is the limit.
The solution is conceptual, and not tested in a real life scenario. It proves although, that it IS possible to execute code in real time upon an email being opened.
Keep an eye out for shortcomings of open tracking in general, as described in this Litmus article.
